# Lasso in R package glmnet: solution not optimal?

Tags: r, minimization, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am just trying to understand the lasso implemented in R package glmnet.
I am fitting the data but the solution I get for a lambda of my choice is
not minimising the criteria of the lasso, for instance if I move the solution in one way 
I can get a smaller cost function.

What am i understanding wrong?

```
library(lattice)
library(Matrix)
library(glmnet)
# Target vector
Target <- c(1.3906275E7, -1.8241672E7, 8181847.0, 1.6927098E7, -6547966.5, -1363836.375)


# Observation vector
Obs <- matrix(c( -0.944, 0.869 ,-0.795,-0.996, 0.617, 0.886,
                -0.472 , 0.936 , 0.063 ,-0.080,-0.751 ,-0.834,
                -0.107 , 0.343 , 0.261 , 0.327,-0.255,0.705,
                -1.803,-0.781,0.168,0.211,-0.349, -0.040),6,4)


#fitting
fits <-glmnet(Obs,Target)

# arbitrary choice of lambda
lambda <- 221800
coef = predict(fits,s = lambda  ,type="coefficients")
res = c(coef[2,1],coef[3,1],coef[4,1],coef[5,1])


# Computing the lasso criteria
newbookrisklassor  = Target-Obs%*%res
cost = sum(abs(res))
newRisklassor = t(newbookrisklassor) %*% newbookrisklassor+lambda*cost



# Moving solution slightly in 1 way and computing the lasso criteria
epsilon = 500000
resP = res + c(0,epsilon,0,0)
costP = sum(abs(resP))
newbookrisklassorP  = Target-Obs%*%resP
newRisklassorP = t(newbookrisklassorP) %*% newbookrisklassorP+lambda*costP


# Error it seems that the resP solution is better
newRisklassor-newRisklassorP
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the intercept in the fitting 
newbookrisklassor  = Target-Obs%*%res- intercept...